# VISIO 2016 --> How To Remove Shape From A Container?

Tags: wireless-networking, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013, layers, container

### The Issue

I have a Visio 2016 network diagram which has two layers. Layer A) contains a container full of network shapes (router, firewall, switch, access point). Layer B) has a giant House graphic. What I want is for the house graphic to exist behind the router group, but the house keeps getting automatically added into the container, which expands the container size.

### My Questions

1. How do I remove a shape from a group in Viso 2016?
2. Why is my house getting automatically added in the container?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem. Though, simpler - I just want some shapes not to be included in a container. 
Please, [have a look at this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/784d8169-5b22-4a52-9198-33ebac0dc057/cross-functional-flowchart-solution-shapes?forum=visiogeneral).

Solution to my problem:

1. To the shapes, I want to be included NOT, I create a User-defined
   cell `User.msvShapeCategories` and set its value to `DoNotContain`
2. To the container I create a User-defined cell `User.msvSDContainerExcludedCategories` and set its value to `DoNotContain`

And voala! My shapes are no longer included in the Container.

As far as I could get it, you can use user-defined cell  `User.msvSDContainerRequiredCategories` to each layer and tell it what shapes to include and then create an user-defined cell `User.msvShapeCategories` for each shape and set respective value.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Wow ... It's been almost 2 years since I posted this and yours is the first answer I've had. I look forward to testing your solution!

Answer (score 0):

an idea, that works for me with Visio 2019:

0. unlock the container if it is needed
1. select and cut (ctrl-x) the items you want to remove from the container
2. resize the container if you want
3. lock the container
4. paste (ctrl+c) the items again (connectors need to get reconnected again)

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind.